# Create new git repos from exist git cloned project

Tags: drupal, repository, clone, git

I have some repos cloned from http://drupal.org/project/
For work behind firewall, I want to import these cloned project to my local git server. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by importing?

Comment: When use import I mean: each project which I cloned from Drupal will be available in my git server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each cloned repository can be used as a server.

If I correctly understand your needs, you just have to push to your own server from the checkout.

You can be interrested in some of the `git push` command like `--all`

So a command like `git push --all <url of your repository>`